# I want to get the dictionary key based on its values

Tags: python

I wanted to return the key but first do the comparison using the value, I want to get the key, not get the value

````
lista_prefixos: List[Dict[str,str]] = [
                        {'RUA': ['RUA', 'R']}, 
                        {'PRAÇA': ['NOSSA', 'PRAﾇA', 'PRACA', 'PCA', 'PC']}, {'TRAVESSA': ['TV']},
                        {'AVENIDA': ['AV', 'AVENIDA']}, {'VIA': 'VIA'}, {'MARGINAL': 'MARG'},
                        {'VIADUTO': ['VIAD', 'VIADUTO']}, {'RODOVIA': ['RODOVIA', 'ROD']},
                        {'ALAMEDA': ['AL', 'ALAMEDA']}, {'LARGO': ['LGO', 'LARGO']},
                        {'ESTRADA': ['ESTRADA', 'ESTR']})

def ajusta_dados(lista_prefixos: List[Dict[str,str]], busca_rua):
    lista_logradouro = []
    for x in lista_prefixos:
        RUA, PRAÇA, AVENIDA, VIADUTO, ALAMEDA,
        ESTRADA, TRAVESSA,VIA, MARGINAL, RODOVIA, LARGO = x.keys())
        if Rua_certa == x.keys():
            Rua_certa = x.values()```
````

Comment: There is an issue with your parenthesesis no? Here: `['ESTRADA', 'ESTR']})`. Could you provide an example output?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you please provide an example output? What is Rua_certa?

Comment: You have a lot of mistakes. `listo_prefixos` ends in the wrong character. Your typehints are incorrect. You are unpacking the list in the wrong order. `Rua_certa` is never defined. `busca_rua` is never used. Arbitrary tildes at the end of your program. You want keys but you are storing values.

Comment: o problema era os () quando eu apaguei e usei o que o rapaz mandou deu certo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from typing import List, Dict

lista_prefixos: List[Dict[str, List[str]]] = [
    {'RUA': ['RUA', 'R']},
    {'PRAÇA': ['NOSSA', 'PRAﾇA', 'PRACA', 'PCA', 'PC']},
    {'TRAVESSA': ['TV']},
    {'AVENIDA': ['AV', 'AVENIDA']},
    {'VIA': ['VIA']},
    {'MARGINAL': ['MARG']},
    {'VIADUTO': ['VIAD', 'VIADUTO']},
    {'RODOVIA': ['RODOVIA', 'ROD']},
    {'ALAMEDA': ['AL', 'ALAMEDA']},
    {'LARGO': ['LGO', 'LARGO']},
    {'ESTRADA': ['ESTRADA', 'ESTR']}
]

def ajusta_dados(lista_prefixos: List[Dict[str, List[str]]], busca_rua: str) -> str:
    for prefixo in lista_prefixos:
        for key, values in prefixo.items():
            if busca_rua in values:
                return key
    return "Not Found"

# Example usage:
search_term = "LGO"
result = ajusta_dados(lista_prefixos, search_term)
print("Found:", result)
```

Output:

```
Found: LARGO
```

Comment: The typehints should be `list[dict[str, list[str]]]`. Using the typing module for theses base types is deprecated, and the hint was also wrong.

Comment: for reference [typing deprecated](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#deprecated-aliases). I see you fixed the hint, but you are still using the deprecated way. Also you left the first typehint wrong.

Comment: Your code will pass awkwardly on VIA and MARGINAL because their values are not list[str]. Also, those values being str breaks the typehint.

Comment: @TheHungryCub in that case when I search for "VI" it's returning "VIA". But there are no "VI" defined. It should return Not Found?

Comment: @EmidioNeto - it's because VIA and MARGINAL have str instead of list values..

Comment: I fixed your oversights but left your deprecated way of type-hinting.

Comment: That's correct. I saw your edit. Now it'r returning Not Found.

Comment: @EmidioNeto - isn't that what you want it to return when you put in the wrong search term?

Comment: @OysterShucker I just stated that it was returning what was expected. I'm sorry, I expressed myself poorly.

Comment: Thanks @OysterShucker & EmidioNeto for helpful/knowledgable discussion.

Comment: @OysterShucker tá carente filho?

Comment: @vituu999 - Seu comentário é muito vago.